# Let Scope output

Tags: javascript

Can anyone explain why the first console in test function gives the value 99.

```
let l = 99;

function test(){
    console.log(l);
    if(true){
        let l = 7;
        console.log(l);
    }
}

test();
console.log(l);
```

Answer (score 0):

Added comments for explanation

```js
// global scope
let l = 99;

function test(){
    // console.log(r); can't be accessed here
    // can see only the global scope
    console.log(l);
    if(true){
        // only limited to this scope
        let l = 7, r=0;
        // l overides the global scope 
        console.log(l);
    }
    // console.log(r); can't be accessed here
}

test();
// can see the l only in the global scope
console.log(l);
```

to learn about the scope of let please refer to this [MDN blog](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)